# Why did God make such a vast, expansive universe?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, science, creation, size

The title pretty much says it all — but it certainly seems unnecessary and plays very well into the theories of people such as Richard Dawkins. How are we best to respond to this challenge of theirs?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty good... Wonder if anyone comes up with something more here though...? The alien thing also?

Comment: Re aliens see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/50731/revisions

Comment: I think your username answer it.